# How to display an Heat Map (using Tableau or other BI tool)?

Tags: tableau, heatmap

I've a simple dataset:

- Id
- Longitude
- Latitude
- Value

What can I obtain at the moment are "one map point" in every place.. Sum of Value don't affect "density" color. 
I would like to display a Geographic Heat Map like this (i copied from Google image). How ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the latitude and put it under rows, select longitude and put it under cols. 
Select value and drop it to the center of the sheet.
And under the marks dropdown select filled maps.

Make sure you see filled maps in the dropdown and that the value column is selected for color.

Edit: Do this for gradual color in heatmap- 
click on color tab.
Select edit Color-now choose stepped color. This should do the work of filled maps with gradual colors.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: This give me a point each record ... Not a "dark red" point if value is high, and "light red" if value is low ... this is not heat map .. This a density map based on row number, not values..

Comment: did you drag value to the color on the marks card and select maps or automatic in the drop down it should fill the areas based on the color palette you chose.